# Laravel & Inertia.js - reactivity problem (vue3)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

could it be that Inertia.js page components are blocking the reactivity of vue?

I have a Page component, in this component is a normal single file component.

I have a function that adds items to the `ItemsManager.items` object.
When I'm running this function the single component below doesnt adds this items in the `v-for`.
But when I'm reload the Page Component it works and the previously added items appear.

***Here the single file component:***

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.$key">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ItemsManager } from "./utils.js";

export default {
    name: "test-component",
    data: () => ({
        items: ItemsManager.items
    }),
};
</script>
```

***utils.js:***

```
export const ItemsManager = {
    items: [],
    add(item) {
        item.$key = this.items.length;
        this.items.unshift(item);
    },
};
```

***function that adds the items (in page component):***

```
addItem(title, options) {
    ItemsManager.add({
        name: title,
        options: options
    });
},
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Vue2, you need to know that there are some caveats when adding/deleting things to Objects/Arrays. You don't show any code relevant to your actual way of adding stuff to your object, but I can still recommend that you'd check this page to understand and fix your issue.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm using vue3 and I added the missing code in the question.

Comment: You're maybe using Vue3 but with option API syntax, so Vue2 essentially. Otherwise, please provide the correct [tag:vue3]. The unshift here, looks fine. What do you vue devtools tell you once you call your `add` method ?

Comment: In the devtools the object stays empty. But when I'm refreshing the page component with the `<breeze-nav-link />` component, the previously added items appear in the object and vue renders them.